# When sine is equal to one (depending on multiplier)?

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

I've made up the equation: $\sin\left(\frac{5n\pi}{2}\right)=1$. Through experimenting I figured that this equation holds for $n = 0.2 + 0.8\,m$. Why is that?

Comment: Is $,$ being used as a decimal here? (It's uncommon in the US but common elsewhere.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know the general answer to $\sin(x)=1$? It is $x=2k \pi + \pi / 2$. Thus:

$$2.5 n \pi = 2k \pi + \pi / 2 $$

Which yields:

$$ n = (4*k + 1) / 5 = 0.2 + 0.8 k$$